# R - 2 for loops to get none 0 data can be optimized?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, nested

Once again I turn to the SO Gods to help me as I am a meere mortal programmer.

I have 2 `DataFrames` Op and fwd.

They are really too big even if I dput the number of lines is too much to put here. This is why I wil only dput the first 20 rows.

```
fwd = structure(list(Dates = structure(c(18779, 18780, 18781, 18782, 
18783, 18784, 18785, 18786, 18787, 18788, 18789, 18790, 18791, 
18792, 18793, 18794, 18795, 18796, 18797, 18798), class = "Date"), 
    CAL1.num = c(2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
    2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
    2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L), CAL2.num = c(2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 
    2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 
    2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L), 
    CAL3.num = c(2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 
    2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 
    2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L), CAL1.prix = c(20.7198630136986, 
    20.5709826758316, 20.5416570682562, 20.1627967508327, 19.5804662519739, 
    19.970595583085, 19.8936930981244, 19.598362502073, 19.8008353366899, 
    19.8038507758495, 19.5289796563554, 19.7658386493753, 19.5078559900235, 
    19.3052695609575, 19.1955268594179, 19.3754495791108, 19.3013180873984, 
    19.4454161579162, 19.8524627413157, 19.8965952683892), CAL2.prix = c(17.9395616438356, 
    17.9420914607196, 17.9607954381744, 17.7250235708918, 17.3068986556031, 
    17.5655735706712, 17.4205222954918, 17.156263873053, 17.3336837635027, 
    17.3420560988812, 17.2226393449218, 17.2839803603736, 17.0980024668028, 
    16.955907646717, 16.9389288476745, 17.1480589434091, 17.034948349062, 
    17.0495808702106, 17.3617641445812, 17.4449687857862), CAL3.prix = c(16.8487431693989, 
    16.7476370720291, 16.6119480947879, 16.3651399362189, 16.069183915644, 
    16.2355843497187, 16.2713389578965, 16.1073762918961, 16.3063152846391, 
    16.3621047950222, 16.3258984487073, 16.3618578134152, 16.2591922615945, 
    16.0804320226449, 16.0739980313506, 16.3870819039359, 16.5066329864522, 
    16.513327927322, 16.7687609933202, 16.8776662523007), QUARTER1.nom = c("Q3 2021", 
    "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", 
    "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", 
    "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", "Q3 2021", 
    "Q3 2021"), QUARTER2.nom = c("Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", 
    "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", 
    "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", 
    "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021", "Q4 2021"), QUARTER3.nom = c("Q1 2022", 
    "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", 
    "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", 
    "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", "Q1 2022", 
    "Q1 2022"), QUARTER4.nom = c("Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", 
    "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", 
    "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", 
    "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q2 2022"), QUARTER1.prix = c(24.4009782608696, 
    23.8791293344845, 23.6895439878102, 23.1986796056566, 22.3253285022921, 
    22.6640748439239, 22.7646092945935, 22.281369465237, 22.4915701163657, 
    22.2460826351854, 21.9641008808891, 22.3943073066212, 21.9430552443109, 
    21.5838423137683, 21.5216100604998, 21.7183538434616, 21.6178630431267, 
    22.0840523702174, 22.5758311437561, 22.5797108901139), QUARTER2.prix = c(25.2263043478261, 
    24.7192160211123, 24.5643273242301, 24.1333672230736, 23.4826299624358, 
    24.0155578900935, 24.1022650172914, 23.854421232743, 23.9063239026515, 
    23.7167326854575, 23.3461717065084, 23.6767791363945, 23.2928412004004, 
    22.8239297903667, 22.8206587737937, 22.9449903236577, 22.9170029906723, 
    23.2600872568113, 23.7352326859226, 23.7318277693714), QUARTER3.prix = c(25.5061111111111, 
    25.0924453041838, 24.9438104415761, 24.4516395089059, 23.734597082601, 
    24.1836860520103, 24.2425714820358, 23.9608801643543, 24.0077045012931, 
    23.8625790300674, 23.4938582233503, 23.8204360345224, 23.4585802827627, 
    23.0648009364399, 23.0503755079289, 23.2072021288566, 23.1679045472902, 
    23.4704615774202, 23.9887249226929, 24.0296246878244), QUARTER4.prix = c(18.8628571428571, 
    18.7936780601555, 18.76113878006, 18.3719593325938, 17.8063028446364, 
    18.1714236251237, 18.0405795878287, 17.6842019501597, 17.9633497185463, 
    18.0350331708269, 17.812021591911, 18.0312294037435, 17.789591687912, 
    17.6312927680928, 17.4703292692614, 17.6630817559893, 17.5288070986573, 
    17.6155053427362, 17.9832674813674, 18.0256484510743), MONTH1.nom = c("M7 2021", 
    "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", 
    "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", 
    "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", "M7 2021", 
    "M7 2021"), MONTH2.nom = c("M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021", 
    "M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021", 
    "M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021", 
    "M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021", "M8 2021"), MONTH3.nom = c("M9 2021", 
    "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", 
    "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", 
    "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", "M9 2021", 
    "M9 2021"), MONTH4.nom = c("M10 2021", "M10 2021", "M10 2021", 
    "M10 2021", "M10 2021", "M10 2021", "M10 2021", "M10 2021", 
    "M10 2021", "M10 2021", "M10 2021", "M10 2021", "M10 2021", 
    "M10 2021", "M10 2021", "M10 2021", "M10 2021", "M10 2021", 
    "M10 2021", "M10 2021"), MONTH1.prix = c(24.56, 24.0316394164205, 
    23.8305607727713, 23.3221443581862, 22.4181924739579, 22.7652505249174, 
    22.8359195995121, 22.3440978554473, 22.5744708270217, 22.296982351325, 
    22.0146497904558, 22.4464255212171, 21.9827906537189, 21.6061923844531, 
    21.5728465276548, 21.77154858271, 21.6812999231947, 22.160502823575, 
    22.6461706466308, 22.6825679056712), MONTH2.prix = c(24.33, 
    23.8197624908486, 23.6363342114893, 23.165393738618, 22.3090561325133, 
    22.6543048025027, 22.7611323512942, 22.2877324620753, 22.4832702720456, 
    22.2509377861053, 21.9572024521086, 22.3882935479875, 21.9350221930074, 
    21.5849317681906, 21.5175910522709, 21.7067681832549, 21.6032068733244, 
    22.0762504646336, 22.5643986056167, 22.5493770956657), MONTH3.prix = c(24.31, 
    23.7828813215745, 23.5988100788821, 23.1054947573159, 22.2461838470091, 
    22.5696223496993, 22.6945148209203, 22.2099750319535, 22.4144825544854, 
    22.1884692725573, 21.9189953840767, 22.3466660354603, 21.9102961409363, 
    21.5596214711576, 21.4728186862763, 21.6753577951185, 21.5674563091854, 
    22.0131155375179, 22.5149606135297, 22.5047702283011), MONTH4.prix = c(24.76, 
    24.2277487078825, 24.0712491465489, 23.6427115413029, 23.0102312371408, 
    23.5583299448447, 23.6502693471086, 23.4325414986478, 23.4861175143973, 
    23.3201907140291, 22.9323618250847, 23.2700400258469, 22.8766635305259, 
    22.399491320035, 22.3966520753529, 22.5201036501858, 22.4954814039879, 
    22.8385990939485, 23.3133721389017, 23.3282933797103)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")


Op = structure(list(Dates = c("2021-06-01", "2021-06-02", "2021-06-03", 
"2021-06-04", "2021-06-05", "2021-06-06", "2021-06-07", "2021-06-08", 
"2021-06-09", "2021-06-10", "2021-06-11", "2021-06-12", "2021-06-13", 
"2021-06-14", "2021-06-15", "2021-06-16", "2021-06-17", "2021-06-18", 
"2021-06-19", "2021-06-20"), `M6 2021` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    `M7 2021` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M8 2021` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `M9 2021` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M10 2021` = c(-0.73, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `M11 2021` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M12 2021` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    `M1 2022` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M2 2022` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M3 2022` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M4 2022` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `M5 2022` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M6 2022` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M7 2022` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `M8 2022` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M9 2022` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M10 2022` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `M11 2022` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M12 2022` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    `M1 2023` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M2 2023` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M3 2023` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `M4 2023` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M5 2023` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M6 2023` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M7 2023` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M8 2023` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M9 2023` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M10 2023` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M11 2023` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M12 2023` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M1 2024` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M2 2024` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M3 2024` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M4 2024` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M5 2024` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M6 2024` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `M7 2024` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M8 2024` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M9 2024` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `M10 2024` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M11 2024` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `M12 2024` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M1 2025` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M2 2025` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M3 2025` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M4 2025` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M5 2025` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M6 2025` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M7 2025` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M8 2025` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M9 2025` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M10 2025` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M11 2025` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `M12 2025` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Q2 2021` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Q3 2021` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Q4 2021` = c(0.73, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q1 2022` = c(0.51, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `Q2 2022` = c(-0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q3 2022` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q4 2022` = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q1 2023` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `Q2 2023` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q3 2023` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q4 2023` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q1 2024` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `Q2 2024` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q3 2024` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q4 2024` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Q1 2025` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Q2 2025` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Q3 2025` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Q4 2025` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Y 2021` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Y 2022` = c(0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Y 2023` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Y 2024` = c(0.88, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `Y 2025` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want to do is:

1. Select the rows from Op where there is a value that is not a zero (let's say rows 1, 2 have values)
2. For each one of these rows (1, 2) select the columns where there is not a 0
3. Loop over these columns of these rows to get that column name
4. Find that column name in the DataFrame called fwd
5. Get a value from fwd based on the name and type of the column name as well as the row value
6. Multiply this value by the value of Op
7. Sum these values up

The code I have that I need help optimizing is:

```
      res = 0
      
      Mat = Op
      
      for (i in which (rowSums (abs (Mat[, -1])) != 0))
      {
        for (j in (which (Mat[i, -1] != 0) + 1))
        {
          produit = colnames (Mat)[j]
          
          if (substr (produit, 1, 1) == "M") prix = fwd[i, which (as.character (fwd[i, ]) == produit) + 4] 
          if (substr (produit, 1, 1) == "Q") prix = fwd[i, which (as.character (fwd[i, ]) == produit) + 4] 
          if (substr (produit, 1, 1) == "Y") prix = fwd[i, which (paste0 ("Y ", fwd[i, ]) == produit) + 3]
          
          res = res +  as.numeric (Mat[i, j] * prix)
        }
      }
```

Comment: What exactly are you multiplying? Can you give the first few expected output ie `Op[1, 'M10 2021']`  is greater than zero. What will it be multiplied with?

Comment: Also should the names of `fwd` have the suffix `nom` or `num`?

Comment: Your fundamental problem is that your data are not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  Make them so, and your life will become easier: no loops for a start!  Also, your problem is not well-specified.  In step 4, there are no column names in `fwd` that satisfy the filter derived in steps 1-3.  There are , however, columns that *contain* these values.  Please clarify your problem.

Comment: your colnames in Op and fwd are totally different, so step-3 you have stated is meaningless?

Comment: To answer the comments:

1) the expected output res is just the sum of the multiplication of the value in Op by the value in fwd

2) the suffix is .nom (as in name in french)

3) yes colnames(Op) != colnames(fwd), but no step 3 isn't useless since you are searching for the column name of Op in row i. You are searching for what column (j) it is in to add 4 or 3 to j to get the value you want to multiply with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
Op %>%
  pivot_longer(-Dates) %>%
  filter(value != 0 ) %>%
  mutate(Dates = as.Date(Dates)) %>%
  left_join(pivot_longer(fwd, -Dates,
                         names_to = c('key', '.value'), 
                         names_sep = '\\.') %>%
              mutate(name = coalesce(nom, paste('Y', num))),
            by = c("Dates", "name")) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value*prix))

 A tibble: 1 x 1
  value
  <dbl>
1  62.9
```

Comment: I will check this out and tell you

Comment: you had forgotten the cal column it needs to have the correct name to be merged on. I fixed it and its now ok so I put a correct because it was just a simple correction that was needed. thx